# Get Object from http get API result

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I know question has already asked but I can't do it with my get result.

My service get data from API return this kind of result :

```json
{
    "nhits": 581,
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "communes-belges-2019",
        "rows": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "facet": [
            "niscode",
            "region",
            "nis_code_region"
        ],
        "format": "json",
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "datasetid": "communes-belges-2019",
            "recordid": "65d40b7bc42f766b4fdb04c4a985766dc8b51717",
            "fields": {
                "shape_area": 79397718.576,
                "mun_name_upper_fr": "ÉTALLE",
                "arr_name_fr": "Virton",
                "region": "Région wallonne",
                "niscode": "85009",
                "mun_off_language": "FR",
                "geo_shape": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                5.678490965,
                                49.687217222
                            ],
                            [
                                5.678462422,
                                49.6873304
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon"
                },
                "prov_name_fr": "Luxembourg",
                "namefre": "Étalle",
                "nom_commune": "Étalle",
                "nis_code_region": "03000",
                "mun_name_fr": "Étalle",
                "reg_name_fr": "Région wallonne",
                "mun_area_code": "BEL",
                "modifdate": "2007-01-05",
                "mun_type": "Commune/Gemeente/Gemeinde",
                "mun_name_lower_fr": "étalle",
                "prov_code": "80000",
                "year": "2021-01-01",
                "geo_point_2d": [
                    49.6639160352,
                    5.60896600843
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.60896600843,
                    49.6639160352
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2019-05-24T09:44:14.333000+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "facet_groups": [
        {
            "name": "niscode",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "11001",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "11001"
                },
                {
                    "name": "33021",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "33021"
                },
                {
                    "name": "33029",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "33029"
                },
                {
                    "name": "33037",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "33037"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "region",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "Région flamande",
                    "count": 299,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "Région flamande"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Région wallonne",
                    "count": 262,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "Région wallonne"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Région de Bruxelles-Capitale",
                    "count": 19,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "Région de Bruxelles-Capitale"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "nis_code_region",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "02000",
                    "count": 299,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "02000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "03000",
                    "count": 262,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "03000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "01000",
                    "count": 19,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "01000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For the moment my service get data like this :

```js
  getProvinces(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this._http.get<any>(this.apiProvinces)
      .pipe(
         map((response: any) => response.records as any[]),
         catchError(this.handleError)
         )         
  }
```

It returns a Observable<any[]> but I would like to get an object.

Therefore I defined a class with the below properties.

```js
export class Record{
    region      : string;
    nom_commune : string;
    prov_name_fr: string;
    records?: [];

    constructor(reg: string, commune: string, prov: string) {
        this.region = reg;
        this.nom_commune = commune;
        this.prov_name_fr = prov;
    }
}
```

To reach that I try by replacing any[] by Record[] like below but it doesn't work.

```js
  getProvinces(): Observable<Record[]>{
    return this._http.get<Record[]>(this.apiProvinces)
      .pipe(
         map(response => response as Record[]),
         catchError(this.handleError)
         )         
  }
```

In my component I defined an Observable<Record[]> like this :

```js
public results$!: Observable<Record[]>;
```

And call the service like this :

```js
this.results$ = this.apiService.getProvinces();
```

And try to see content in the html part:

```html
<div *ngFor="let p of (results$ | async)">
     {{p | json}}
</div>
```

I have the following error message : "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

And can't access to my object.

Any suggestions is helpfull because. I'm absolutely new to ANgular.

Thanks

Comment: Use Interface instead of class

Comment: I changed my class to an interface but nothing change. I also updated my question.
Why using an interface in place of a class?

Comment: Am I missing something or you didn't state the problem? What's happening at the end, which error do you have?

Comment: In your http.get it cannot be records. use any there.

Comment: I changed Record by any like this ```typescript this._http.get<any[]>(this.apiProvinces) ``` but same result (error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an observable, you don't actually make a request to your api. To make the request and get the data from the observable, you need to `subscribe`.

```js
this.apiService.getProvinces().subscribe((res) => (this.results = res));
```

This will execute the get request and return your data to the callback function. Get requests are finite observables, so you don't need to unsubscribe, but you will need to subscribe again if you want to make another request.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I do the subscription now in the component but I always have the error message : "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: I think that error message is pretty clear, you're trying to use `*ngFor` on an object and not an array. Just remove `*ngFor` from your html, or use one of the array properties of your results, such as `records`.

Comment: Yes I also think that the problem comes from the records array and the structure of the get response. I'm trying like this ```typescript

this.apiService.getProvinces().pipe(
      map((response: Record[]) => response))
      .subscribe((response: Record[]) => {
        this.results = response
      });
``` 
but result becomes "undefined" in the console

Comment: Yes you are using the map operator incorrectly, just remove it. In your subscription, do `this.results = response.records` if you want the array of records. Your response is NOT an array of records, it is the object you showed at the start of the question correct?

Comment: Alternatively you can do `map((response: Record[]) => response.records)`

Comment: Keep in mind the result will be undefined until you receive a response, so you may be doing a `console.log()` too early.

Comment: In both cases I have the error : "records doesn't exist in Record (interface)"

Comment: Yes because you have declared your results as type `Record[]` incorrectly. Just declare your results as type `any` or `{records: Record[]}`

Comment: I created a StatckBlitz project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8hvluu?file=src/app/app.module.ts because it's too confused

Comment: Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6gthi?file=src/app/app.component.ts takes about 5-10 seconds to get a response.

Comment: Just fixed your definition of a record, it was way off what the actual object looks like. Now it prints out the `nom_commune` of each record.

Comment: Ok thanks. But what is the type of fields now? An object? If that's so, a Record is an  object containing another object (fields)? Which itself contains fields?

Comment: Your results are the object you posted in your question. I presume a `Record` represents an object found in the `records` array property. So, a `Record` contains all of the properties found in one of these objects. One of those properties is `fields` as seen in your question. The property `fields` is an object containing many other properties. You yourself posted the object structure, maybe you should study it a bit closer. Curly brackets `{ }` indicate an object, square brackets `[ ]` indicate an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your explanations. It's more clear now.